# App crashes when try to connect to a webserver

Tags: android, crash, webserver

I want to know why my application crash when i try to connect to the webserver to send / retrieve data from it.

Sometimes it works fine, but sometimes i get the error - Unable to resolve host "URL" No address associated with hostname - , even if the internet and webserver is on. I noticed that when the google play is updating apps, this error occurs more frequently. Anyone knows why that happens and how to prevent this crash? Below is the code i'm using.

```
//Manifest
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


class new_message extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... String) {

        try {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id));
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_message,"POST", params);

            if (json.getString("message").matches("nothing")) {
                flag = false;
            }else{
                flag = true;
                String att = json.getString("message");
                db.open();
                db.att_message(id, att);
                db.close();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        if (flag) {
            Intent msg = new Intent(context, Mensage.class);
            context.startActivity(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace for a crash and point out in your code the line where the crash occurred. Also please explain what `jsonParser` is.

Comment: Post your `makeHttpRequest` function's code.

Answer (score 0):

### Try this

```
 @Override
 protected String doInBackground(String... mEntity) {

 try {
     HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
     HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
     HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(App_URL);
     httppost.setEntity(mEntity);
     HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
     HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();  
     result = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
     Log.d(TAG, result);
     jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
 } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```